# Write file A to file B in python

Tags: python, file

In Python, have a file A, and I want to copy it to file B.  What's the most efficient way to do that? I will also be appending further text to file B after the initial copy. Thanks.

Comment: `write or writelines` in `ab` mode ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like use `file.write()`...

```
with open('A', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

with open('B', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

About append, use append mode(`a`) when you write text:

```
with open('A', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

with open('B', 'a') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(A,B)
```

Then use **B** as a regular file.